# Laravel 4.1, call error message for specific validation point of one input / possible?

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4, validation

I have a question concerning the Laravel 4.1 validators.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
array('name' => 'Dayle'),
array('email' => 'required|min:5|unique:users')
);
```

Is it possible to call a specific validation error for the case when the entered email is not unique? Reading the docs I only saw that one is able to define the error message if the validation for 'email' fails. However, if someone enters an email address but this one is already in the database it would be awesome to show the user exactly that he passed "required" but did not pass "unique".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of `Validator::make()` lets you pass in an array of messages. More on this here: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-error-messages

As it says in the above link, you can specify field-and-rule-specific messages by using the dot syntax `email.unique`. In your case this would be:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array('name' => 'Dayle'),
    array('email' => 'required|min:5|unique:users'),
    array('email.unique' => 'This email is already being used by another user.'),
);
```

Comment: How would I call this one in the views then? The way I have seen it is like this: <?php echo $errors->first('email'); ?>

Would that have to be 'email.unique' then?